# Not displaying search results

Tags: php, mysql

My php/MySQL search query is returning no errors nor is it displaying the results from the MySQL table. For example, I have 6 rows and each column contains 3-5 words(separated by commas). If the user types in a certain word matching a word a specific column, it should pull and display only that/those row(s). Can someone point me in the right direction, Here's my code(database connection works fine btw)

```
include('database.php');

echo "<div class='grid_4'>
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='search' maxlength='60' size='20px' placeholder='Under  Construction...'/>
<input type='submit' name='ssearch' value='Search' id='favb'>
</form>
</div>";

if(isset($_POST['ssearch']) && $_POST['ssearch'] != "")
{   
$SB=$_POST['ssearch'];

$search=$db->prepare("SELECT body FROM thread WHERE body LIKE ?");
$search->execute(array('%'.$SB.'%'));
$search->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sR=""; 

while($row=$search->fetch())
{
$title=$row['title'];
$thread_id=$row['thread_id'];
$preview=$row['preview'];

$sR.='<div class="grid_3" id="previewmargin">
<a href="view_thread.php?id='.$thread_id.'" id="tt">'.$preview.'</a></div>';}
}
echo $sR;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$SB=$_POST['search'];`? ssearch is the name of the submit button.

Comment: @andrewsi I agree. Plus I'm also questioning `if(isset($_POST['ssearch']) && $_POST['ssearch'] != "")` whether that should also reflect the same? As in `if(isset($_POST['ssearch']) && $_POST['search'] != "")` however I could be wrong.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - good point; I'd not noticed that!

Comment: @andrewsi It can't be left out of the equation. Having more than one set of eyes on such, is more effective.

Comment: I changed it but results still do not display.

Comment: @user2895014 Then the problem may lie in `LIKE ?` which probably should read as `LIKE '%$SB%'` and modifying `$search->execute(array('%'.$SB.'%'));` to reflect those changes. Other than that, it's a debugging issue.

Comment: 'Reflect those changes' How? $search->execute(array($SB)); Like that?

Comment: @user2895014 Not 100% sure but try `$search->execute();` - search queries are not my forté.

Comment: Does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

At the line where you run the search, if you change from:

```
$search->execute(array('%'.$SB.'%'));
```

to:

```
$search->execute(array("'%" . $SB . "%'"));
```

Comment: have you tried `print_r($search->fetch());` to see the return?

Comment: If you tried before the block "while", then you are not going through your condition.
Look debug variables with "print_r" to make sure that the conditions are being met.

Comment: You need change "ssearch" to "search" on your condition and on attribuition of variable $SB